# asp command object execute error on parameters including encoding

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, command-objects

I am running a query using a command object but getting an unexpected error  executing a query I need some help with.

The same code appears to work just a few lines above and seems to have only appeared after I replaced the original db table to a -dev copy table.

The code is as follows:

```
sql = "SELECT blah, blah... " &_
        "FROM tracker p " &_
        "LEFT JOIN ... " &_
        "LEFT JOIN ... " &_
        "WHERE p.id = ? "
Dim cmdObj : set cmdObj = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdObj.ActiveConnection = conn
cmdObj.CommandText = sql
cmdObj.Parameters(0) = sID
Set rs = cmdObj.execute()
```

This runs fine and I store out some results. 
I then run another query over the next lines use the same parameter:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table-dev p WHERE p.id = ? "
cmdObj.CommandText = sql
cmdObj.Parameters(0) = sID
Set rs = cmdObj.execute()
```

generates the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.95-log]You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '-dev p WHERE p.id = _latin1'21115'' at line 1
```

I am hoping someone can point in the right direction why this might be showing now and throwing the encoding to the parameter. I have seen this before and managed to find a fix but can't for the life of me remember how.

All help greatly appreciated. 
Many thanks,
JB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the keyword `table` is confusing the query engine.  Just wrap the identifiers in back-ticks to make them explicit:

```
SELECT * FROM `table-dev` p WHERE p.id = ?
```

Comment: The table name used was not actually called "table" but once I used the  back-ticks it seemed to work!! Thanks for that. Was driving me a bit crazy and the thought of the back ticking never entered my head.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Could it be that MySQL is expecting an explicit `AS` for the aliasing, and the backticks work around that?

Comment: @Martha: I don't think so.  Though without knowing what the *actual* code is which caused the problem (since the OP apparently decided to change it for the question), it could be anything.  Even an errant whitespace character between the name and `-dev`.  The only thing clear form the error message is that the problem is immediately before the hyphen.